# I have powershell command where each content needs to in inserted into cells of aexcel

Tags: powershell, export-to-excel, powershell-3.0

Hi i am new to the Powershell and needed below output need to be inserted into cells of excel book

```
systeminfo | findstr /B "Domain"
Get-LocalGroupMember -Group Administrators
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product
Get-TimeZone
get-culture | format-list -property *
Get-NetFirewallProfile | select Name, enabled
get-wmiobject -class win32_logicaldisk


$nicx = Get-NetAdapterStatistics
Foreach ($nic in $nicx) {
  Get-NetAdapterAdvancedProperty -Name $nic.Name -DisplayName "Receive Buffer Size"
  Get-NetAdapterAdvancedProperty -Name $nic.Name -DisplayName "Send Buffer Size"
}

Get-NetAdapterBinding -ComponentID ms_tcpip6
```

the output for the commands will be like

```
PS C:\Users\> systeminfo | findstr /B "Domain"
Domain:                    example.net
PS C:\Users> Get-LocalGroupMember -Group Administrators
ObjectClass Name                             PrincipalSource
----------- ----                             ---------------
User        server\admin         Local          
User        Example-NET\a_pra              ActiveDirectory
Group       Example-NET\Admin_server ActiveDirectory
Group       Example-NET\Domain Admins        ActiveDirectory

PS C:\Users> Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product |  findstr -i "Snow Inventory Agent"
Name              : Snow Inventory Agent
Vendor            : Snow Software AB
Caption           : Snow Inventory Agent
Name              : Microsoft Monitoring Agent
Caption           : Microsoft Monitoring Agent

PS C:\Users> Get-TimeZone 
Id                         : Central European Standard Time
DisplayName                : (UTC+01:00) Sarajevo, Skopje, Warsaw, Zagreb
StandardName               : Central European Standard Time
DaylightName               : Central European Daylight Time
BaseUtcOffset              : 01:00:00
SupportsDaylightSavingTime : True
```

etc all commands outputs need to formatted into a excel .

Comment: Capture the output(s) and build a `[PsCustomObject]` where you set the results to properties. Then use [Export-Csv](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv) to write the info to a CSV file on disk you can open/import into Excel

Comment: Please add an example of how you expect the excel file to look. Most of those commands output multiple objects with their own properties. The simplest way to get all the output in csv format is add ` | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | Out-File -Append -Path 'c:\path\file.csv'`  to the end of each command

Answer (score 0):

This is a good starting point, but you'll have to provide more infomation if you want it formatted differently:

```sh
$ExcelFile = 'c:\folder\filename.csv'

systeminfo | findstr /B "Domain" | Out-File -A $ExcelFile
Get-LocalGroupMember -Group Administrators | ConvertTo-Csv -NoType | Out-File -A $ExcelFile
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product | ConvertTo-Csv -NoType | Out-File -A $ExcelFile
Get-TimeZone | ConvertTo-Csv -NoType | Out-File -A $ExcelFile
Get-Culture | ConvertTo-Csv -NoType | Out-File -A $ExcelFile
Get-NetFirewallProfile | select Name, enabled | ConvertTo-Csv -NoType | Out-File -A $ExcelFile
Get-WmiObject -class win32_logicaldisk | ConvertTo-Csv -NoType | Out-File -A $ExcelFile

Foreach ($nic in (Get-NetAdapterStatistics)) {
  Get-NetAdapterAdvancedProperty -Name $nic.Name -DisplayName "Receive Buffer Size" | ConvertTo-Csv -NoType | Out-File -A $ExcelFile
  Get-NetAdapterAdvancedProperty -Name $nic.Name -DisplayName "Send Buffer Size" | ConvertTo-Csv -NoType | Out-File -A $ExcelFile
}

Get-NetAdapterBinding -ComponentID ms_tcpip6 | ConvertTo-Csv -NoType | Out-File -A $ExcelFile
```

In excel you'll still have to do Data > Text-to-Columns since you have multiple tables with different fields